# Create a dashboard for online users

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a requirement and i think i need your help to start it.Actually i have created an application which monitors the status of users which are saved in mysql database with their status.By status i mean 4 types Online,Offline,LoggedIn,LoggedOff.So according to these status i need to display them on the dashborad.Isearched in internet about possible plugins or something,but alas! couldn't find any relevant article.I think this needs css.I am not sure how to start it.Can anyone share some ideas about the same ?

Comment: Given how many dashboard examples and products are out there I find it hard to believe you didn't find anything. Any charting product or library includes a dashboard sample.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Any links related to it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should start with Bootstrap framework, it is created atop of CSS and JS. Here is nice template that you can use as a starting point. [SB Admin 2](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/)

Comment: Will it be able making it with MVC 4 razor ?

Comment: Yes, you can use ASP .NET MVC 4 for accessing DB and business logic, and nice user interface can be done with template above.

Comment: Ok, thanks. IF you have any more clear links then let me know

Comment: Since bootstrap is part of VS templates now, you will quickly get it on. Here is something useful, http://responsivemvc.azurewebsites.net/Bootstrap. If answer helped you, please be mark it :-)

Comment: Marked it as answer, Do let me know if you get something in details. Thanks :)

Comment: Please don't encourage awful questions.  We have quite enough of those, thank you.

Comment: Okay, I was not thinking in that way, just wanted to help. But your comment make sense. Cheers.